# How to save user entered values in XForms textbox

Tags: xforms

I am pretty new in xforms. and this question seems to b very simple. I have an xform which contain two text boxes and a button control. I want that when a user submits the form, the values in the text box are stored in the xform model. How I can do this?

Code is given below, when i click on the button , values in the model element doesnot change.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="formfaces.js"></script>


<form:model>
    <form:instance>
    <data xmlns="">
<textbox1>0</textbox1>
<textbox2>1</textbox2>
<textbox3>2</textbox3>
<textbox4>3</textbox4>
</data>

</form:instance>
<form:submission action="Text.html" id="submission" method="put" replace="instance"/>
</form:model>
</head>


<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form:input ref="/data/textbox1">
<form:label>TextBox1</form:label>
</form:input>
</td><td>
<form:input ref="/data/textbox2">
<form:label>TextBox2</form:label>
</form:input>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><form:input ref="/data/textbox3">
<form:label>TextBox3</form:label>
</form:input>
</td><td><form:input ref="textbox4">
<form:label>TextBox4</form:label>
</form:input>
</td></tr>



</table>
<form:submit submission="submission"><form:label>Submit</form:label></form:submit>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As @grtjn said, this should be working automatically, but if you've tried and it isn't working for you, maybe you can share your code with us so we can reproduce the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I shared the code. please respond , how we can slove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be taken care of automatically.

But if you are trying to display model changes on the screen immediately, make sure to add `incremental="true"` attributes to the xforms input elements, so that each keystroke generates update events, and xforms output elements are refreshed as well.

**added:**

You seem to be submitting to an html. I am guessing it is the html containing the form itself. You don't need to call it like that to get the model updated. You typically call a script with a PUT submit to get it stored on the server. A PUT usually doesn't return something either, though it could return a copy of what you were PUT'ing.

I took your code a made two important changes to show the model is updated automatically. I copied your table of form inputs and renamed the inputs to outputs. I also added the incremental attribute on the inputs to get the outputs updated after each keystroke. You may also notice I added a bit of CSS, but that is just to make label and value of the outputs distinguishable:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:form="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="formfaces.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            label {
                display: block;
                float: left;
                clear: both;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 1em;
                width : 110px;
            }
        </style>


<form:model>
    <form:instance>
    <data xmlns="">
<textbox1>0</textbox1>
<textbox2>1</textbox2>
<textbox3>2</textbox3>
<textbox4>3</textbox4>
</data>

</form:instance>
<form:submission action="test.xml" id="submission" method="put" replace="instance"/>
</form:model>
</head>


<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form:input ref="/data/textbox1" incremental="true">
<form:label>TextBox1</form:label>
</form:input>
</td><td>
<form:input ref="/data/textbox2" incremental="true">
<form:label>TextBox2</form:label>
</form:input>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><form:input ref="/data/textbox3" incremental="true">
<form:label>TextBox3</form:label>
</form:input>
</td><td><form:input ref="textbox4" incremental="true">
<form:label>TextBox4</form:label>
</form:input>
</td></tr>



</table>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form:output ref="/data/textbox1">
<form:label>TextBox1</form:label>
</form:output>
</td><td>
<form:output ref="/data/textbox2">
<form:label>TextBox2</form:label>
</form:output>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><form:output ref="/data/textbox3">
<form:label>TextBox3</form:label>
</form:output>
</td><td><form:output ref="textbox4">
<form:label>TextBox4</form:label>
</form:output>
</td></tr>



</table>
<form:submit submission="submission"><form:label>Submit</form:label></form:submit>


</body>

</html>
```

If you replace the value of the submission action attribute with a reference to some .asp script, it will get called, and will receive the entire instance in the request body. Make sure to return a complete instance, as it will be replaced.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks...! one more thing I want to ask. can you please guide me how we can call a script with a put submit to get the values stored in an xml file on the server. I tried and able to load values from the xml file but I donot know, how to store values in that file. I am using asp.net for server side and sql server for database

Comment: @zeeshan-hasan I added a paragraph to the end. I hope it helps you get further.

Comment: thanks sir...! your suggestions helped me alot. Can you send me a sample .asp script for the above mentioned code, (i.e for the four text box values) , so that i could know how this script can b written. Actually I am building a web- based X-Form builder as my final year project and I am struck here. (at server side). please help me to get out of this. I am really grateful to you, and i will b honour for me if you give me personal assistance to complete this project

Comment: I can share my complete code to get better understanding , if you are interested. @ grtjn

Comment: @zeeshan-hasan I'm not very familiar with Asp(.net), but I think if you search on stackoverflow or internet on how to print request parameters and request body with asp you'll surely find enough to get going.